# New questions show editors, not the people that asked

Tags: discussion

Part of the process of this web site is to clean up the questions. Which is a great idea as we have a diverse audience and sometimes the questions are marred with language due to English not being their main language or the formatting is bad as they haven't used the web site before.

So after we cleanup the post our name gets put next to the question because we have modified it. The a good editor will keep the essence of the question and doesn't really contribute to the question. So why feature that person? I have no interest the user XXX edited a question. I want to know who raised the questions, especially on new questions.

Once someone has actually answered the question then its fair to replace the "questioners" details with the last person.

Otherwise we think the editors raised the question and we pop in to have a look to find out its some new user asking how to install Ubuntu.

I like to help out new users and I like to take on the challenge of a question from a more experienced user. Under the current system its very difficult to distinguish between the new users and the more experienced users new questions.

Having to pop into the question to find out is just using server resources for no reason and also a waste of time for myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The a good editor will keep the essence of the question and doesn't really contribute to the question.

No. He obviously contributes to the post positively (in majority of the cases). It's his edit that makes the post more readable and understandable for the next reader. Moreover, the content at Stack Exchange Network is licensed under [CC-By-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), so the edit gets attributed under the name of the editor.

> Once someone has actually answered the question then its fair to replace the "questioners" details with the last person.

Doesn't make sense to me at all.

> I like to help out new users and I like to take on the challenge of a question from a more experienced user. Under the current system its very difficult to distinguish between the new users and the more experienced users new questions.

You should [use this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest) for what you want. You can access it by clicking Questions → and then Newest.

[image: questions-newest]

This page only shows the name of the user who asked the Question. Whereas, the front page shows the user who performed the last activity on that particular Question.

Comment: Never noticed, always used the front page newest. Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: Here it is the other way around once more: I guess I've never seen the "front page" before :-)